# Django TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <homeworkForm bound=True, valid=Unknown, fields=(title;descripiton;due)>

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to allow staff users to post homework to a database however I keep running into the issue above. I've tried setting `data['id'] = 0/''` as well as dropped the table and makemigrations/migrate.

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from teachers.models import Teacher


class Homework(models.Model):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  descripiton = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  due = models.DateField()
  teacher = models.OneToOneField(
      Teacher, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

form.py

```py
from django import forms


class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'


class HomeworkForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label='Title', max_length=100)
    descripiton = forms.CharField(label='Descripiton', max_length=500)
    due = forms.DateField(label='Due', widget=DateInput)
```

views.py

```py
def homework(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated & request.user.is_staff:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.POST.copy()
            data['teacher'] = request.user.username
            request.POST = data
            print(request.POST)
            form = HomeworkForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = Homework(form)
                post.save()
                messages.info(request, 'Form sent')
                print('worked')
                return render(request, 'index/index.html')
            else:
                print('error in form')
                form = HomeworkForm()
                return render(request, 'dashboard/setHomework.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            form = HomeworkForm()
            return render(request, 'dashboard/setHomework.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the answers. I managed to fix the issue by converting the form to a model form as that form model works better for the situation as the model fields are mapped directly to the inputs.

new forms.py

```py
from homework.models import Homework
from django import forms

class HomeworkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Homework
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'due']
        widgets = {
            'due': forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%Y'), attrs={'label': 'due date', 'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try data['teacher'] = request.user instead of data['teacher'] = request.user.username ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `request.POST.copy()`, `request.POST` is already a dictionary.

Comment: you do. otherwise, you can't mutate the post